# Layered Window in Android

Tags: android

I want to have an activity with window that layering another window like Linkbubble
[image]

How to create that kind of window?
I already have the bubble created using windowmanager.

Comment: The best way to create this is by using an overlay with service. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use frame layout or merge tag to host your layers.. each layer can be any layout. each child in framelayout comes on top of the previous.

Comment: I succeed to create the bubble icon using window manager.
how to make the layout below that bubble icon?
it's nice if you can put some sample codes

Comment: create the whole layer (bubble + below layout) with a vertical linearlayout or relative layout. 

and this layout should be placed in the top level framelayout

Comment: sorry but I'm not really good with Android UI
the bubble is coming from window manager, so I didn't use frame layout.
Is it not possible by only using windowmanager.addView(...) ??